# modificar chosen e ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, chosen-jquery-plugin

**Chosen**

Como modificar o valor data-placeholder: através do javascript 
ex:

```
<select data-placeholder="Para:" name="cd_aluno[]"id="cd_aluno"  multiple class="chosen-select">
```

alterar o data-placeholder com o js

**CKEditor**

Como desabilitar o textarea do ckeditor (disabled)
Ex:

```
<textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="email" rows="15"style="margin-top: 2px;"></textarea>

document.getElementById("editor1").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Para alterar o `data-placeholder`, use o [`.data()` do JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$('#cd_aluno').data('placeholder', 'novo valor');
```

---

Para desabilitar o CKEditor (torná-lo somente leitura), você pode configurá-lo na inicialização, definindo a opção de configuração `CKEDITOR.config.readOnly` para true. Por exemplo:

```
config.readOnly = true;
```

Outra forma é definir o atributo `disabled` para o elemento `<textarea>` que o CKEditor substitui. [Veja esse exemplo](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/readonly.html), que permite habilitar e desabilitar o modo somente leitura do CKEditor.